# Cakephp in Xampp server cannot connect to mysql server to a database with password

Tags: cakephp, xampp

I have got the following error when I try to open my cakephp in browser

CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.

Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have the database "caketest" and access as root with my password '1234'
As I search in many sites they have told to grant access to all so I tried:

grant all privileges on caketest.* to 'root'@'localhost';
flush privileges;

that also doesn't work...

I have wamp server and bitnami tomcat also. So to avoid conflict I have changed my port number of xampp server to 16

My C:\xampp\htdocs\caketest\app\Config\database.php is as follows

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '1234',
    'database' => 'caketest',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

should I change anything else
I have tried many things. But it doesn't work! Please help me!

Comment: Have you restart your mysql service after the change of permission?

Comment: hi Minoccheri, thanks for response. yeah! I did! it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'host' to '127.0.0.1'